# Is it possible to access client harddisk using asp.net or any client side technology

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Actually I want to store a file on a client PC.

I know that asp.net does not allow to access client harddisk but by using any trick or any idea?

For security reasons I want to save a file on client's computer containing user information. I does not want to save a cookie in a user's browser.

Scenario.
I want to store something on client's PC permanently by using which I identify the user. Everytime when user login to mysite I will check that file on client's PC. If file is present then user will login sucessfully if file is deleted by the user or by any reason file is deleted or user comes from another PC then again save a file on client's PC. I does not want to save something on browser bcz user may delete the cookies and other histroy.

Don't mark my question as negative, I don't have any harmful intention.

Comment: Using Flash or ActiveX you can accomplish this rather nefarious task in a sandboxed fashion.

Comment: +1 for the question; I know it's a bad idea to do, but it's a clear question with a clear answer.

Comment: Any hacker would like to do this too.

Comment: I suppose the real question is how to store data in a persistent manner at the client side? This could be done e.g. using a cookie or - in modern browsers - using HTML 5 web storage. See http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html to get some overview.

Comment: Update: Looks like you real issue is to store a persistent authentication cookie, sth. as described here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/009e2e5e-5a44-4050-8233-59a0d69844e8/basics-forms-authentication-in-aspnet-20.aspx

Comment: @epascarello. I'm not a hacker. The question I want to know when the user comes from another PC to my site.

Comment: @J.Steen. How with ActiveX ? any link

Comment: @waqar +1 for a good edit for question clarity

Comment: "I does not want to save something on browser bcz user may delete the cookies and other histroy." How are you going to prevent the user from deleting anything else - such as a file - from its own system? Why re-invent the wheel and not use a persistent cookie for your purpose?

Comment: I only want to identify client machine. I searched and found that it is not possible to get Mac address of client machine. What can I do with persistent cookie ?

Comment: Why do you care if the user switches machines?

Comment: @Quentin. It is the client's requirement. When user comes from a new computer then save a new file in the client computer in order to recognize it.

Comment: And why does the client require it? I can't think of any reason to want it unless you are producing some very obscure statistics or have some ill-advised DRM scheme that compromises one of the biggest advantages of web services.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.

Any technology that lets you store files will throw up a stack of security warnings.

Comment: Not quite true. A cookie is a file on stored on the client and browsers usually don't ask for permission to store that file. Another option is HTML5 Web Storage (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). Of course, storing something locally is not the same as full access to the file system.

Comment: @0xA3 — A cookie is not a file, it is a small piece of data. The browser can store it anyway it likes, some browsers use files to do so. The data you can put in it is far from arbitrary though. The same, more or less, applies to webstorage.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer...no

There are a number of ways to accomplish saving a file to the users machine.  They will all require some form of permission from the user. (i.e. a java applet will need trust)

The advantage here is that if you self-sign your applets and use the same sig for all of them then you can obtain trust through another applet and it is then extended to your file writing applet.(if they check the box too)  However the user will always have to click at least once that they trust you.

Note that even if trust is extended like this they may well see another trust box asking them to trust microsoft to do file operations(in the case of win systems)...they will always know whats going on

EDIT: Just had a thought, depending on what you want to save you may be able to squeeze it into a cookie or a batch of cookies.  A lot of users have these always on and will never know....sneaky

Comment: thanks for replying. How to do this with  asp.Net ? or any .net technology . I never work on java applet

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx - this provides a good overview and syntax for asp.net cookies. If looking to use an applet then it gets embedded into a webpage with the tag <embed> as shown here http://www.echoecho.com/applets01.htm , the applet itself will need to be written in java but im sure you can google up source for one

Comment: huh, that applet site i linked to is still using <applet>.  Use <embed> or it wont work in many browsers

Answer (score 0):

No, it's highly unsafe to have access to the client PC without any permission.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to store a file on a client PC without telling to the client." - that is where the real problem lies. You should not do this. And the browser is designed to stop you doing this, quite rightly.

You need to go back and look at what you are wanting to do, and do it differently.

Comment: ok is it possible install something on client PC from the web site by asking user that we want to save some security information on your PC ?

Comment: you could lie to and misdirect your users by telling them you are doing A and then do B instead....but its bad form.  If you really need to save the file then tell them whats in it and let them choose since you are asking anyway

Comment: ok I will tell the user that we want to save some security info on your PC. If user allow us than how can I save a file or install something on client's PC from the site

Answer (score 0):

This is break a fundamental security principle of Web Applications